# Switching serialization b/w json and xml in WCF response for non-"GET" methods

Tags: c#, xml, json, wcf

In a WCF REST service I am switching the response serialization between JSON and XML based on the value specified in Accept HTTP header. I am using IDispatchMessageFormatter as described here - http://damianblog.com/2008/10/31/wcf-rest-dynamic-response/.

I am using Content-Type for PUT and POST, but the IDispatchMessageFormatter.SerializeReply it self does not get executed in the case of PUT and POST.

The only problem is that this works only for GET requests and not for PUT, POST, DELETE etc. does anybody know why? Or am missing something very basic here :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved the problem ..... the current code was only handling WebGetAttribute:

```
class WebHttpBehavior2Ex : WebHttpBehavior
{
    protected override IDispatchMessageFormatter GetReplyDispatchFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, 
                                                                           ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        WebGetAttribute webGetAttribute = operationDescription.Behaviors.Find<WebGetAttribute>();
        DynamicResponseTypeAttribute mapAcceptedContentTypeToResponseEncodingAttribute = 
            operationDescription.Behaviors.Find<DynamicResponseTypeAttribute>();

        if (webGetAttribute != null && mapAcceptedContentTypeToResponseEncodingAttribute != null) {
            // We need two formatters, since we don't know what type we will need until runtime
            webGetAttribute.ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
            IDispatchMessageFormatter jsonDispatchMessageFormatter = 
                base.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
            webGetAttribute.ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
            IDispatchMessageFormatter xmlDispatchMessageFormatter = 
                base.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
            return new DynamicFormatter() { 
                jsonDispatchMessageFormatter = jsonDispatchMessageFormatter, 
                xmlDispatchMessageFormatter = xmlDispatchMessageFormatter };
        }
        return base.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
    }
}
```

Instead we need to handle both WebGet and WebInvoke attributes like below:

```
public class WebHttpBehaviorEx : WebHttpBehavior
{
    protected override IDispatchMessageFormatter GetReplyDispatchFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription,
                                                                           ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        WebGetAttribute webGetAttribute = operationDescription.Behaviors.Find<WebGetAttribute>();
        WebInvokeAttribute webInvokeAttr = operationDescription.Behaviors.Find<WebInvokeAttribute>();
        DynamicResponseTypeAttribute mapAcceptedContentTypeToResponseEncodingAttribute =
            operationDescription.Behaviors.Find<DynamicResponseTypeAttribute>();

        if (webGetAttribute != null && mapAcceptedContentTypeToResponseEncodingAttribute != null)
        {
            // We need two formatters, since we don't know what type we will need until runtime
            webGetAttribute.ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
            IDispatchMessageFormatter jsonDispatchMessageFormatter =
                base.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
            webGetAttribute.ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
            IDispatchMessageFormatter xmlDispatchMessageFormatter =
                base.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
            return new DynamicFormatter()
            {
                jsonDispatchMessageFormatter = jsonDispatchMessageFormatter,
                xmlDispatchMessageFormatter = xmlDispatchMessageFormatter
            };
        }
        else if (webInvokeAttr != null && mapAcceptedContentTypeToResponseEncodingAttribute != null)
        {
            // We need two formatters, since we don't know what type we will need until runtime
            webInvokeAttr.ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
            IDispatchMessageFormatter jsonDispatchMessageFormatter =
                base.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
            webInvokeAttr.ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
            IDispatchMessageFormatter xmlDispatchMessageFormatter =
                base.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
            return new DynamicFormatter()
            {
                jsonDispatchMessageFormatter = jsonDispatchMessageFormatter,
                xmlDispatchMessageFormatter = xmlDispatchMessageFormatter
            };
        }
        return base.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For posting values you should use the header Content-Type. This header is commonly used for this type of operations.

As a reference you could take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: I am using Content-Type for PUT and POST, but the IDispatchMessageFormatter.SerializeReply it self does not get executed in the case of PUT and POST.